# A question about subharmonic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

On the article about subharmonic functions, wikipedia says

> In the context of the complex plane, the connection to the convex functions can be realized as well by the fact that a subharmonic function $f$ on a domain $G\subset\mathbb{C}$ that is constant in the imaginary direction is convex in the real direction and vice versa.

Am I correct in interpreting this as saying that if $f(x+iy)$ is a subharmonic function, then by setting $y=c$ and considering $\phi(x)=f(x+ic)$, $\phi$ is a convex function? If so, does anyone know how to prove this or give a reference?

Thanks!